# Can I enforce one function as both right associate and left associate in scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like define scalar multiply vector just as following:

```
Vector * scalar   (1)
scalar * Vector   (2)
```

I could define * as the function of class Vector which implement the first case. Then how can I implement the second case, one way I can think of is using the right associate function, but it require me to add "::" in the function name which is not readable. I want the second case just looks like the first case.  How can I make it in scala ? Thanks

Comment: You can use standalone functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do some pimpin' of the library.

For the first case:

```
class MyVector(vector: Vector[Double]) {
   def *(scalar: Double) = vector.map(_ * scalar)
}

implicit def vectorToMyVector(vector: Vector[Double]) = new MyVector(vector)
```

Then for the second case you do something similar:

```
class Scalar(value: Double) {
   def *(vector: Vector[Double]) = vector.map(_ * value)
}

implicit def doubleToScalar(value: Double) = new Scalar(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an implicit conversion from the scalar type into a class that has a `*(x: Vector)` method. It can be as simply as

```
implicit class ScalarVectorMult(scalar: Double) {
  def *(vector: Vector): Vector = vector * scalar
}
```

That needs to be put inside a package object or an object -- putting it directly on a package won't work.